# Regarding passing pointers as arguments

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to code a basic zero threshold function. such that if the value of the array element is greater than zero must remain same else it must be zero. But my problem is with passing the array values from main to the function using pointers. Here's the snippet. `im` is the input array and `im2` is the array to store result. `t` is the threshold which is 0 and `m` is the order. On passing the input array from main to thresh function. I just checked the values of im in thresh function but all were showing 0, as commented in code below, instead of original values. where am i going wrong??

```
int thresh(double *im[], double *im2[], int t, int m)
{
    int i, j;
    printf("im:%f", im[0]); //here i am getting output as zero instead of 1
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        if (im[i] > t)
            im2[i] = im[i];
        else
            im2[i] = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    float im[4] = { 1,-2,3,-4 };
    float im2[4];
    int th = 0;
    thresh((float*)im, (float*)im2, th, 2);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (im[i] > t)` You are comparing a pointer to an int here.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks i noted. But still why am i not getting the initial array values as i have printed in the code. I am getting zero. any idea?? Thanks

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings ! You should get [a bunch of warnings](https://ideone.com/Zk4m43) for the above code as there are a number of obvious problems, most of which the compiler will catch if you let it.

Comment: Why are you mixing `float` and `double` anyway? Never use `float` unless you absolutely have to due to system or library constraints. This isn't 1984.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on compiler warnings and read them. They are there to help. This is what I got on compilation:

```
$ gcc main.c 
main.c: In function ‘thresh’:
main.c:10:23: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
             if (im[i] > t)
                       ^
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:24:12: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘thresh’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     thresh((float*)im, (float*)im2, th, 2);
            ^
main.c:4:5: note: expected ‘double **’ but argument is of type ‘float *’
 int thresh(double *im[], double *im2[], int t, int m)
     ^~~~~~
main.c:24:24: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘thresh’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     thresh((float*)im, (float*)im2, th, 2);
                        ^
main.c:4:5: note: expected ‘double **’ but argument is of type ‘float *’
 int thresh(double *im[], double *im2[], int t, int m)
     ^~~~~~
```

So there is some stuff to fix.

First of, the prototype for `thresh` should be `int thresh(double *im, double *im2, int t, int m)` or even better `int thresh(const double *im, double *im2, int t, int m)`

Second, why are you mixing `float` and `double`? Stick to one, and stick to `double` unless you have a really good reason.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable suggestion. will try out this.

Comment: Turning on warnings is absolutely the most valuable suggestion you can be given at this point. To clarify: you need to add warning-enabling switches to your command line. A typical recommendation is `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`.